# Are there any good sources of documentation on the file format of picasa.ini files

Tags: picasa

It would be nice to know how this file is structured and all its possible sections, keys, and values.  Does anyone know of documentation on the file format?

Answer (score 8):

Here is a good one [.picasa.ini decoded](https://gist.github.com/1073823/9986cc61ae67afeca2f4a2f984d7b5d4a818d4f0) reverse-engineered  for Picasa Version(s): 3.8.0 by Franz Buchinger

You might want keep track of the following feature request for Shotwell [#1930 (Import albums/meta info from Picasa)](http://trac.yorba.org/ticket/1930)

And have a look at [avpicfacexmptagger](http://www.anvo-it.de/wiki/avpicfacexmptagger:main) for ideas.